# Postfix connection refused

Tags: postfix, dovecot, spamassassin

So I recently set up Postfix and Dovecot with SpamAssassin for my email server and I tried using telnet to test SMTP and on all SMTP ports (25, 465, 587), I receive connection refused. I've set IP Tables and UFW. When executing `netstat -tulpn | grep 25` or any other SMTP port nothing shows up.

main.cf: https://hasteb.in/egogugoz.cf

master.cf: https://hasteb.in/pucepije.cf

Comment: Ehm... Can we get more information? Like what output do you get from `/var/log/mail.log` when you try to (re)start postfix service? And if your system uses Systemd: What is the output from `systemctl status postfix.service`?